# XSLT matching with namespaces

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, lxml

I am trying to build bottle.py templates from RelaxNG definitions using Python 3.6 and lxml (which means XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0). I cannot find the trick to getting the name of the starting template, which in this example is 'AddressBook'. I need this from *rng:grammar/rng:start/rng:start/rng:ref/@name* instead of *rng:define/@name*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">
<start>
<ref name="AddressBook"/>
</start>

<define name="AddressBook">
<element name="addressbook">
  <zeroOrMore>
    <element name="card">
      <element name="name">
        <text/>
      </element>
      <element name="email">
        <text/>
      </element>
    </element>
  </zeroOrMore>
</element>
</define>
</grammar>
```

This is my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:rng="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
                exclude-result-prefixes="rng">
<xsl:output type="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <div>start
  <xsl:apply-templates select="rng:start"/>
  done</div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rng:start">
  <div>Start
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="rng:ref/@name" /></h1>
  End</div>
</xsl:template>
```

The first match works and I get

```
Start End
```

as a result of this transformation.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with namespaces, but with paths. Your instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="rng:start"/>
```

does not do anything because `start` is not a child of the current node (which is the `/` root node matched by `<xsl:template match="/">`).

Either change it to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="rng:grammar/rng:start"/>
```

or - preferably, IMHO - start with:

```
<xsl:template match="/rng:grammar">
```

---

P.S. `xsl:output` takes a `method` attribute, not `type`.  And if you're outputting XML/HTML, do not make your output method `text`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the match="/" would automatically be the top level grammar node.

Comment: It *is* the top node. But the *root element* is not the top node of the tree; above it is the *root node* - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node